# Como personalizar os botões para redes sociais?

Tags: css3, facebook, twitter-api

Eu queria saber como faço para personalizar os botões para compartilhamento de algo em alguma rede social. Na *web* já existem os botões padrões mas eu queria personalizar eles só usando CSS. Eu pretendo fazer como esses aqui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKbt0.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:
Aqui neste exemplo vamos estar a utilizar a [**font-awesome**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) para demonstração mas depois tu podes trocar e utilizar imagens em vez de estares a usar a `font-awesome` se preferires, para evitares de estar a carregar a fonte completa para o teu site, caso não a estejas a utilizar em mais lado nenhum

Para usar a `fonte-awesome` primeiro precisamos de a implementar no `<head>` do nosso site, usando a seguinte linha de código:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

De seguida iremos então criar o nosso HTML e CSS:

```css
/* Social Button CSS */
.share-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 4em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.share-btn:hover {
    color: #eeeeee;
}

.share-btn:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #e2e2e2;
    outline: none;
}

.twitter     { background-color: #55acee; }
.google-plus { background-color: #dd4b39; }
.facebook    { background-color: #3B5998; }
.stumbleupon { background-color: #444444; }
.reddit      { background-color: #FFA500; }
.linkedin    { background-color: #4875B4; }
.email       { background-color: #444444; }

/* Código para botão com texto */
.long-share-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.long-share-btn:hover {
    color: #eeeeee;
}
.long-share-btn:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #e2e2e2;
    outline: none;
}
a.long-share-btn {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/&text=<TEXT>&via=<VIA>" target="_blank" class="share-btn twitter">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</a>

<!-- Google Plus -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" class="share-btn google-plus">
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
</a>

<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" class="share-btn facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>

<!-- StumbleUpon (url, title) -->
<a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn stumbleupon">
    <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon"></i>
</a>

<!-- Reddit (url, title) -->
<a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn reddit">
    <i class="fa fa-reddit"></i>
</a>

<!-- LinkedIn -->
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=<URL>&title=<TITLE>&summary=<SUMMARY>&source=<SOURCE_URL>" target="_blank" class="share-btn linkedin">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
</a>

<!-- Email -->
<a href="mailto:?subject=<SUBJECT&body=<BODY>" target="_blank" class="share-btn email">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</a>

<br><br>

<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank" class="long-share-btn facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meus problemas. Eu só gostaria de saber mais uma coisa. Como eu faço isso com o botão de like do Facebook?

Comment: Infelizmente eu penso que isto não seja possível de se fazer utilizando o **botão Like** pois este comporta-se de forma diferente. Mas se estás à procura de adicionar o contador de `likes/shares` a um destes botões do Facebook personalizados, dá uma vista de olhos a [**esta pergunta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72606/11886) para veres como podes adicionar um `contador` personalizado ao teu botão